# iOS 13 Animating View Not Changing Frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, ios13

I have an app which is compiled in Xcode 10 on iOS 13 simulator. In one view there is a "tray" view which shows from the bottom when tapped, in iOS 12 it works perfectly, in iOS 13, the tap is calling the method, but the changes to the frame are not saving - I have included outputs from the debugger in comments so you can see what the outputs of the frame values are;

```
- (void) userClickActivityTray: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer {
if(self.activityTrayShown) {
    /*
     (lldb) po self.activityTrayContainerView.frame
     (origin = (x = 0, y = 792), size = (width = 414, height = 104))
     */
    [self hideActivityTray];
} else {
    if (!self.activityTrayViewInitialFrameComputed) {
        self.activityTrayViewInitialFrameComputed = YES;
        self.activityTrayInitialFrame = self.activityTrayContainerView.frame;
    }

    /*
     (lldb) po self.activityTrayContainerView.frame
     (origin = (x = 0, y = 638), size = (width = 414, height = 224))
     (origin = (x = 0, y = 638), size = (width = 414, height = 224))

     (lldb) po self.activityTrayInitialFrame
     (origin = (x = 0, y = 792), size = (width = 414, height = 104))
     (origin = (x = 0, y = 792), size = (width = 414, height = 104))

     (lldb)
     */

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.activityTrayContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x,
                                                          self.bottomView.frame.origin.y - self.activityTrayViewController.maximumHeight,
                                                          self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                                          self.activityTrayViewController.maximumHeight);

        self.activityTrayBackgroundView.alpha = 1.0;
        self.bottomView.alpha = self.dotsProgressView.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.activityTrayShown = YES;
        /*
         (lldb) po self.activityTrayContainerView.frame
         (origin = (x = 0, y = 557), size = (width = 414, height = 305))
         (origin = (x = 0, y = 792), size = (width = 414, height = 104))
         */
    }];
}
```

}

Comment: Is the issue resolved for you ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Layout system in iOS 13 is different, we had the same issue and in our case by switching `layout` from `automatic` to `Translates Mask Into Constraints` fixed the issue.

[image]

Comment: @Amir.n3t you are correct that this "solve" the problem but it create other problems. I don't think this is the correct approve to just change to the old layout. Instead of animate on the frame you should do it on constraints instead.

Comment: @martinmose Translating masks to constraints has been always enabled by default when defining view in code. This isn't turning off any feature, what problem did it cause for you?  Documentation for your reference :-) [code reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco)

Comment: You are a lifesaver! @Amir.n3t

Comment: Strangely, it gives different width for my UIView in iPhone 8 plus and iPhone X :(

Answer (score 14):

You can use yourview.layer.frame instead of yourview.frame 
It worked for me.

Comment: Paul Ho, you helped me like a God. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: oh my god, you just solved my issues. I was confused as hell because it works smoothly on ios 12.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when moving to iOS13.
In my case, the sizing constraints were overriding any change I was making to the frame, which was not the case on iOS12.
For my app to work correctly, I had to also update the NSLayoutContraint just before the "animateWithDuration" block, so that the new frame coordinates stay compatible with the layout constraints.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

only set .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints 's View to YES, it worked for me.
Hope that helps