# ViewController navigation within a Container view in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, ios13

I have a container View in my OnboardingViewController. Inside OnboardingViewController's viewDidLoad method, I decide which ViewController to be shown in a container view. The ViewController inside container view is embedded in a Navigation Controller.

While pushing viewController inside container view, I am using an animation for UIViewControllerContextTransitioning.

Now when I am pushing another view controller inside container view, I am facing a UI issue where I can see edges of OnboardingViewController for some time and then it disappears after some time showing a full pushed viewController.

This issue is only happening on iOS 13. Working fine on >iOS 13 devices.

I got a reference for View layout changes in iOS 13 :
[iOS 13 Animating View Not Changing Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597413/ios-13-animating-view-not-changing-frame#)

This solution kind of worked for me, but it is leaving some other UI impacts.

Tried to apply :
self.containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

This also solves the problem by impacting some UI issues.

I am aware of modalPresentationStyle changes on iOS 13. But I am not sure if my issue is related to that or not.

Any clue could help me a lot. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Most of the things are done in storyboard.